# How to capture a keyboard event with PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, keyboard, pyqt5

I need to capture a keyboard event and print it to console. I'm new to PyQt and  programming.

I've read about QKeyEvent but can't understand how it work and how i can use it.

in pseudocode, i think it will be look like this:

```
def captureEvent():
    While True:
        if keyBoardButton wasUsed:
            print('KeyBoard was used now')
```

I don't need to know what button on keyboard was pressed, i need only event of it and print it event every time when event is happening. I mean if i tap on keyboard buttons right now it should be printed in console